# Used saveRDS to save a model but not enough memory to readRDS?

Tags: r

I created a model based on a very large dataset and had the program save the results using

```
saveRDS(featVarLogReg.mod, file="featVarLogReg.mod.RDS")
```

Now I'm trying to load the model to evaluate, but `readRDS` runs out of memory.

```
featVarLR.mod <- readRDS(file = "featVarLogReg.mod.RDS")
```

Is there a way to load the file that takes less memory? Or at least the same amount of memory that was used to save it?

The RDS file ended up being 1.5GB in size for this logistic regression using caret. My other models using the same dataset and very similar caret models were 50MB in size so I can load them.

Comment: "but readRDS runs out of memory" what error message do you get? Do you try to read in a clean session?

Comment: It says it cannot allocate 174MB of memory. In task manager I can watch the memory run out. I'm going to try re-booting. My memory is now sitting at 2GB after running gc()

Comment: I'm wondering whether the compression algorithm is more resource intense when decompressing the RDS. I will have to try: saveRDS(object, file = "",
        compress =FALSE, refhook = NULL)

Comment: The model is only 689MB!? The RDS is huge and then is taking 10GB to open?

Comment: I was able to open the file on another computer. My only option otherwise was to use 

    `saveRDS(featVarLogReg.mod, file="featVarLogReg.mod.RDS", compress = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

The caret linear model saves the training data in the model object. You could try to use `returnData = FALSE` in the `trainControl` argument to `train`. I don't recall if this fixed my issue in the past.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-77/topics/trainControl

You could also try to just export the coefficients into a dataframe and use a manual formula to score new data.

Use `coef(model_object)`

Comment: I did set that flag. Not sure why my models/files are still so large. I may try the coef() trick when I get home in the morning. Didn't think of that one.